Are they going to put/hold off the wedding till May?
I am trying to translate a dialogue into English.
Which is idiomatic:
1.
— Are they going to put off the wedding till May?
— Yes, they couldn't get it organized any earlier.
2.
— Are they going to hold off the wedding till May?
— Yes, they couldn't get it organized any earlier.
If both sound ok, what's the difference then?

Obviously in your context they mean the same thing. But relatively speaking, hold off is incredibly uncommon (it's mostly just "corporate speak" for delayed, suspended).

hold off is not incredibly uncommon. He held off on answering the questions but was pleasant otherwise. MW: : to block from an objective : DELAY
2: to defer action on : POSTPONE, hold off a decision. OR to refrain from doing something.

In AmE, we say hold off on something versus impede someone: hold off

They both mean to delay something in this context. However, "put off" suggests something has caused the delay while "hold off" usually means that a required condition has not been met.
For example:

We have decided to put off the event until next week as it is raining this week.

We have decided to hold off the event until my friend can make it.


In your example, as existing delays/unreadiness is the cause, 'put off' seems more appropriate. However, you could make the unreadiness a future condition by saying "they are holding off until they are fully organised".

They held off the bandits at the entrance to the hacienda. BUT: They held off on the wedding for another six months.
